# Terraform using random provider with count in module

Tags: terraform

I am having child module for Windows virtual machine.
Then I have root module (*main.tf* file), where I am using that child module

```
module "vm-win-resource" {
  source = "./Modules/ServerWindows"

  count         = 2
  vm-name       = "vm-win-${random_string.rnd.result}" #OR "vm-win-${module.rnd-num.rnd-result}"
  vm-rg         = module.rg-resouce.rg-name
  vm-location   = module.rg-resouce.rg-location
  nic-name      = "vm-win-${random_string.rnd.result}-nic1" #OR "vm-win-${module.rnd-num.rnd-result}-nic1"
  nic-rg        = module.rg-resouce.rg-name
  nic-location  = module.rg-resouce.rg-location
  nic-ip-subnet = "HERE IS SUBNET ID"
}
```

In same *main.tf* file, if I use *random_string* provider directly

```
resource "random_string" "rnd" {
  length      = 4
  min_numeric = 4
  special     = false
  lower       = true
}
```

or if I create module, for random number and use it in module for virtual machine, result is same.

```
module "rnd-num" {
  source = "./Modules/RandomNumber"
}
```

I get same name (generated number for both)

```
 + vm-win-name = [
      + [
          + "vm-win-6286",
          + "vm-win-6286",
        ],
    ]
```

So in both cases, value is generated only once.

**Question is** how can I generate random number for every *loop* in module for virtual machine?

Thank you for any help!

**UPDATE**
As workaround, I have placed provider to generate random number into virtual machine resource/module specification

```
resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "vm-resource" {
  name                = "${var.vm-name}-${random_string.rnd.result}"
  resource_group_name = var.vm-rg
  location            = var.vm-location
  size                = var.vm-size
  admin_username      = var.vm-admin
  admin_password      = var.vm-adminpwd
  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.nic-resource.id,
  ]

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = var.vm-os-disk-type
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = var.vm-os-image.publisher
    offer     = var.vm-os-image.offer
    sku       = var.vm-os-image.sku
    version   = var.vm-os-image.version
  }

  tags = var.resource-tags
}

resource "random_string" "rnd" {
  length      = 4
  min_numeric = 4
  special     = false
  lower       = true
}
```

it does the job **but** I would prefer to use it in *main.tf* file and not directly in resource/module specification, if it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few words about how Terraform `random_string` works:

- `random_string` generates a random string from specific characters. This string is generated once. Referencing its `result` attribute in multiple places will provide you the same output. Using it as `random_string.rnd.result` will not act as a function call, this means that it will provide the same value in every place.
- The `result` value of a `random_string` will not change after consecutive applies. This is obvious, if we think about it. If it would change, the usage of `random_string` would be dangerous, since it would result in re-provisioning the resources which are referencing it.

If we want to have multiple different random strings, we have to define multiple `random_string` resources. For example:

```
resource "random_string" "rnd" {
  count       = 2
  length      = 4
  min_numeric = 4
  special     = false
  lower       = true
}

module "vm-win-resource" {
  source = "./Modules/ServerWindows"

  count         = 2
  vm-name       = "vm-win-${random_string.rnd[count.index].result}"
  vm-rg         = module.rg-resouce.rg-name
  vm-location   = module.rg-resouce.rg-location
  nic-name      = "vm-win-${random_string.rnd[count.index].result}-nic1"
  nic-rg        = module.rg-resouce.rg-name
  nic-location  = module.rg-resouce.rg-location
  nic-ip-subnet = "HERE IS SUBNET ID"
}
```

Please note, we are using a `count` for the `random_string` resource as well.